# VSCode & Delve dap: Can't get the vscode debugger to work when dlv is launched using 'dlv dap'

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, dockerfile, delve

I'm running VSCode 1.66.0 and I'm trying to attach the golang debugger on a running instance of a specific golang-docker-image. I'm able to do this when using 'dlv' but not when using 'dlv dap' and I can't understand why.

I'm following the instructions provided here:

```
 https://vscode-debug-specs.github.io/go/#debugging-running-remote-process
```

Versions used:

- VSCode ver. 1.66.0
- dlv ver. 1.8.2
- Docker Desktop ver. 4.4.4

My launch.json looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Remote Process",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "attach",
            "mode": "remote",
            "port": 2345,
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "showLog": true,
            "apiVersion": 2,
            "dlvLoadConfig": {
                "followPointers": true,
                "maxVariableRecurse": 1,
                "maxStringLen": 200,
                "maxArrayValues": 64,
                "maxStructFields": -1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My dockerfile looks like so (as you can see the resulting image is based on the official image "mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/go:0-1.18"):

```
 # syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
 FROM golang:1.18 as builder
 [...]
 RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=$ARCH go build -gcflags "all=-N -l" -v -o main .

 
 FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/go:0-1.18
 
 WORKDIR /app
 
 CMD ["./main"]
```

The command I use to launch the 'dlv' process inside the running docker instance is this:

```
dlv dap --listen=:2345 --log=true --api-version=2 attach 1 ./app/main
```

The VSCode UI allegedly allows me to attach via:

```
> Debug: Select and Start Debugging -> Attach to Remote Process
```

However the debugger doesn't really get activated in the sense that the breakpoints are not honored and the 'dlv' command shown above doesn't print anything in the output.

If I remove the 'dap' part from the 'dlv' command:

```
dlv --listen=:2345   --log=true    --headless=true     --log-output=debugger,debuglineerr,gdbwire,lldbout,rpc      --api-version=2   --accept-multiclient   --headless  attach  1   ./app/main
```

then the debugger attaches perfectly and works just fine (this is the legacy mode of the dlv debugger if I understand correctly). What gives? Am I missing something?